# associate values to classes in Keras

Tags: python, keras, lstm, multiclass-classification

How can I associate values to classes in Keras?

Input:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Expected:

```
[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6] associated with class 1
[7, 8, 9] associated with class 2
```

The problem is that [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6] come from one file and [7, 8, 9] from another. I have read an example with iris.csv but the samples have same size.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be to merge the two datasets into one like this:

```
X (shape=(3,3))

[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

y (shape = (3,1))

[1, 1, 2]
```

Many classifiers support labels in that format out of the box.

If you need to further process the labels, you can use scikit-learn for that. Have a look at these:

- [LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)
- [OneHotEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder)